# Apple appconnect long waiting for review

Tags: app-store-connect

[Screebnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVqYR.png)I I cannot log in App Store Connect, I always get this message Information Submitted Thanks for providing additional information—it is currently processing and will be reviewed shortly. During this time, you will not have access to App Store Connect and may experience delays with your payments, if applicable.

Any idea how long it take?